# Wrong icons on Stack Overflow site

Tags: bug, status-completed

I have found wrong icons on Stack Overflow hot network questions:

[image]

According to the image, the first icon is for music, but it says movies & tv. The second icon is for movies & tv, but it says personal finance & money.

Comment: When did you see this? We had a few reports that this was already fixed (as of about an hour ago). Did you refresh your browser cache (hard refresh - Ctrl + F5)?

Comment: When I posted my original question I was watching that in that right moment. Now I have refreshed my browser and it is fixed.